# Shut down plasma desktop and everything to save power

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, battery, desktop-environments

My laptop, running KUbuntu23.04 have about 2 hour battery life, and some weekdays I have lecture in a roll longer than 3 hour collectively. So I've been thinking of shutting everything down and keeping only the needed to see if I could get it through.

My imagination is that if I shutdown plasma somehow, I don't have a desktop GUI interface, there wouldn't be activities, tiling, wallpaper, audio, etc., just tty(I mainly only use emacs, so I can use it in tty or fire another x server just for it), and the energy consumption would lower significantly.

Can anyone confirm if that is possible/realistic? and if it is, how can I do it? Thanks=